# Access property of object using constant variable

Tags: php

Why i can't access property of an object using constant variable.

**this is the constant :**

```
define('FLD_CASES_STATUS', 'case_status');
```

**this will not work**

```
$case->TBL_CASES;
```

Comment: `$case->{TBL_CASES};`

Comment: Because what's the difference between `$case->regular_property_access` and `$case->CONSTANT`…?

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks

Comment: @deceze  the problem is my fields name may change later , is there any better situation for that?

Comment: Abstract more. Problem: field names may change later. Solution: ensure the names are only used *once* in the code where they might change, so when they change it's easy to change them just once. Currently you're trying to do that using constants, so you just change one constant. Saner would be to abstract it behind a class whose public interface doesn't change, but whose internal field names you could change at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

class MyObject {

  public $myProperty;
}

define('PROPERTY', 'myProperty');

$obj = new MyObject;
$obj->{PROPERTY} = 5;
echo $obj->{PROPERTY}; // returns 5
```

as easy as possible. but why don't you use constants or statics in your Object?

Comment: the problem is my fields name may change later , is there any better situation for that?

Comment: perhaps save your names in a db or json file and read them like a config? than you can use $object->{$propertyName} to access

Comment: ok let me explain more , suppose my field name is subject in the table and i want to change it to title , your solution will work absolutely and i did the same thing in my own project , my Question is that the best solution ?

Comment: @wahdan thats very abstract ;) and if i understood correctly what you want to do, it is not possible with define(). or constants. all you can do is to use an array and run over it with a foreach. but if this is the best sollution for a database response? i won't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this simple demonstration code:

```
<?php
define('FLD_CASES_STATUS', 'case_status');
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->{FLD_CASES_STATUS} = 'foo';
var_dump($obj->{FLD_CASES_STATUS}, $obj->case_status);
```

The output obviously is:

> string(3) "foo"
>
> string(3) "foo"